# c++ template containing object using same type T

Tags: c++, templates, object, composite

I have a class MemoryPool with the following (shortened to relevant) code:

```
namespace System
{
    template <class T>
    class MemoryPool
    {
    public:
        // only constructor
        MemoryPool(const size_t itemsToInitNow, const size_t maxItems)
            : _maxItemsInMemoryPool(maxItems)
        {
            // initialize itemsToInitNow items immediately
            for(size_t i = 0; i < itemsToInitNow; ++i) {
                _container.push_back(MemoryItemSharedPointer(new MemoryItem<T>(_factory.CreateItem())));
            }
        }
            .. other stuff

    private:
            .. other stuff
        // private data members
        AbstractFactory<T> _factory;
```

When I instantiate an instance of the object elsewhere in my code, such as

```
new System::MemoryPool<ParticleShape>(10, 100);
```

I get the following compile error:

> `System::AbstractFactory<T>::CreateItem(void)` could not deduce template argument for 'T'.

My AbstractFactory class is also a template class, I defined _factory as a private composite object of MemoryPool with type T. I would like it so whenever I instantiated an object of MemoryPool with a type, say MemoryPool of integers, it would initialize the composite _factory with type int.

Is there a way of doing this?

Edit: here is the CreateItem method, in its infancy:

```
 template <typename T>
 inline const std::shared_ptr<T> CreateItem()
 {
      return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T);
 }
```

Comment: I followed most of what you wrote, but it's confusing me: first you say the problem is the compiler complains because you do not specify the template argument T.  Which is true.  Then you say you want something regarding types and int, which I really don't understand.  Can you clarify what you are expecting `System::MemoryPool(10, 100)` to do?

Comment: @John, markdown ate the type arguments, I fixed the question.

Comment: Basically I would like to be able to instantiate a MemoryPool with a type, say that type was int, char, whatever. That would then instantiate a composite AbstractFactory of the same same type, namely _factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've cut out a lot of your code, but at a guess, you have something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class AbstractFactory {
// ......
    template <typename T>
    inline const std::shared_ptr<T> CreateItem()
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(new T);
    }
};
```

The inner template hides the outer value of `T` - to call this, you'd have to do something like:

```
AbstractFactory<Anything> factory;
std::shared_ptr<int> pInt = factory.CreateItem<int>();
```

As you can see, the inner function has a completely independent template parameter from the outer class. You'll probably want to just remove the template parameter from the inner function, so it takes the outer class's template parameter.

Comment: You guessed exactly how I declared my class. Your guess was correct, removing the template parameter from the inner function was exactly what I semantically wanted. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure since the `AbstractFactory` code is missing, but it *appears* that `CreateItem` is a template method within `AbstractFactory` and the compiler can't figure out which version to call.

Comment: I went ahead and added the definition for CreateItem() to the code above, I would like the compiler to instantiate a composite object of AbstractFactory using the same type T that MemoryPool was instantiated with.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say something definite since you don't show *all* the code, but it looks like you need to say `CreateItem<T>()` instead of `CreateItem()`. A function template that has no (regular) arguments cannot deduce any of its template arguments. They must be specified explicitly.